Problem when deriving formula of the momentum of photons in photoelectric emission
Now I know this might be a small error on my part or some wrong assumption taken, but for some reason when I tried deriving the momentum, I ended up with a different value.
The momentum is given as:
$$
p = \frac{h}{\lambda}
$$
Now I tried deriving the same thing with other formulae:
$$
K.E = \frac12mv^2
$$
v = c since it's photons
$$
K.E = \frac12mc^2
$$
Also the basic formula of momentum is
$$
p = mv
$$
$$
p = mc\ (since\ v = c)
$$
$$
m=\frac pc
$$
Substituting m in K.E = 1/2mc$^2$:
$$
K.E = \frac12pc
$$
Now it's known that energy of the photon,
$$
E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}
$$
Also the kinetic energy and energy are both same in this case(Is what I've learned) so
$$
K.E = E
$$
Where,
$$
K.E = \frac12pc
$$
$$
E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}
$$
Now when I equate both the terms:
$$
\frac12pc = \frac{hc}{\lambda}
$$
$$
\frac12p = \frac h{\lambda}
$$
$$
p = \frac{2h}{\lambda}
$$
And this contradicts the original equation,
$$
p = \frac{h}{\lambda}
$$
Could anyone please point out where the mistake was made during the derivation?

The relations $KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and $p=mv$ hold for massive non-relativistic  (that is, $v\ll c$) particles. They cannot be used for photons, as photons are massless and travel at a speed of $c$. Any description of photons requires special relativity.
In special relativity, the energy energy and momentum of a particle follow the energy-momentum relation:
$$E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$$
One can see that for massless particles this reduces to $E=pc$ and thus $p=\frac{E}{c}=\frac{h}{\lambda}$.

The energy of a photon is $E = pc$, without the factor $\frac{1}{2}$.
